# Java 6 VM to call Java 4 VM

Tags: java, serialization, jvm, rmi, java-6

I've inherited a very old application that hasn't been upgraded because it depends on a third party library that is dependent on Java 4.

Getting rid of this third party library isn't going to happen in the near future as a critical part of the system is dependent on it.

I want to bring the Java version of the application up to date and am thinking of moving the dependent jar into its own VM and then having some kind of call between the Java 6/7 VM and the Java 4 VM.

First thoughts are to use RMI. Obvious first question is compatibility between VMs when using different Java versions. The third party lib produces byte streams so the returned data won't be affected by serialization. The data passed in can be manipulated into something that can be passed across if compatibility is an issue.

Is this the right way to go?

Are there better ways?

Comment: I feel like you're wasting your time if you can't actually remove the Java 4 dependency - you gain little security and lots of overhead. What's the actual error, Java is pretty backwards compatible - maybe you can wrap the third-party library so it can run under Java 6?

Comment: RMI is a good choice.  It's probably the easiest option, and from your description of the third party library, it sounds like it's not worth expending any more effort than necessary on it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can do a wrapper as Phillip said in a comment of yours... there are only some minor adjustments that you have to do in your old library
2. you can use RMI... it's safe! I tested it and it's a good approach... you don't have to change old messy code
3. you can also use web services but I prefer RMI

If you have to modify something small and you have too many problems to change the `JVM` (because someone modified some `jdk` libraries [happened to me]) just leave it to java 4... :)

The problem I had was that I needed a library from `jdk 1.5` to use in `jdk 1.4` but my solution was to decompile the `jdk 1.5` one and compile it back with `jdk 1.4`... because the old `jdk` had something modified in it... 
The problem I had on decompiled code is that I couldn't find a very good decompiler that knows about `casting`... and I had some `stackoverflow` errors (but those are easy to fix)

I hope my answer helps you